# Put value of textbox into another textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, date, textbox

I have a start date which is put in a textbox by the user trough a jquery date picker.
I also have an end date textbox which I want to fill with the start date value when the user changed the value of the start date.

So I was thinking of doing a JavaScript and than a when textbox has changed enter value into end date textbox but I don't know how this would be done.

Thank you guys for helping since I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: Can you post your tried code ?

Comment: I could but this is for a very complex calendar system and would be very distracting to read.

Comment: Your second para is quite confusing. Please make it clear.

Comment: explain your question more, what exactly you are trying to do with textboxes

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code for what you have asked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#fromdate").datepicker({
                    onSelect: function() {
                        $(this).change();
                    }
                });
                $("#fromdate").change(function (){
                    var val=$("#fromdate").val();
                    $("#todate").val(val);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="from">From</label>
        <input type="text" id="fromdate" name="from">
        <label for="to">to</label>
        <input type="text" id="todate" name="to">


    </body>
</html>
```

**And working JSFiddle**([**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/prakashcbe/fa9Lq/3/))

Answer (score 1):

If it is [this calendar](http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php), (which it looks like from [your own "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22626560/3278057)), you could do something like this. It will set "*date end*" and pop up calendar for it when *"date from"* is selected:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var cal_start = new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"date_start",
        dateFormat:"%m/%d/%Y"
    });

    var cal_end = new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"date_end",
        dateFormat:"%m/%d/%Y"
    });
    cal_start.addOnSelectedDelegate(function(){
        document.getElementById('date_end').value = cal_start.getSelectedDayFormatted();
        cal_end.showCalendar();
    });
};
```

If you do not want the calendar-end to pop up, remove:

```
cal_end.showCalendar();
```

---

Original answer as per your statement *"[…] trough a jquery date picker […]"* in question text.

jQuery UI variant:

Use `onSelect` event.

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/Lpby2/):

```
$(function() {
    $("#date_start").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(d) {
            $("#date_end").val(d);
        }
    });
    $("#date_end").datepicker();
});
```

You could also add for change event on element, but not sure how user-friendly that would be.

Comment: This what I need acactly but I am not using the same date picker as you are.

Comment: @PieterdeVries: Ah, I see. Is it this one? http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php

Comment: @PieterdeVries: Added an update that might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the simple method below,but if you need something other,let me know

```
function copytextbox()
{
 document.getElementById('textbox2').value=document.getElementById('textbox1').value;

return false;

}
```

Comment: I have this   <input type="text" name="startdate" onchange="copytextbox()" id="startdate" required="required" readonly="readonly" value="04/12/2014"/> but it doesnt do anything when the text changes also id did change the textbox2 and 1 to the propper names

Comment: use inspect element from the browser and get the id,it would have changed

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
    function myfunction()
    {

    document.getElementById("text2").value=document.getElementById("text1").value;
}   
 </script>
```

and your start date textbox-

```
<input type="text" name="startdate" id="text1" onchange="myfunction()"/>
<input type="text" name="enddate" id="text2" />
```